# How to block web traffic for some websites without proxy server

Tags: centos, proxy, squid, squidguard

Hello in our windows environment we need to block or filter internet some websites using Centos 8
For squid proxy server we need to assign group policy or add proxy address one by on which is not possible for us
We need something through centos to filter our internet.Kindly advice necessary.

Comment: To have effect, the squid proxy should either be connected directly by the clients (but you don’t seem to be able to do it), or redirected by something between the client and the Internet (typically a router). If your CentOS system act as a router, its `iptable` should redirect all web traffic to squid.

Comment: Basically options from the router is not enabled by the ISP. So we have to go through squid but clients can bypass proxy server.

Comment: One way is to insert a router you can control between the ISP router and your LAN. This router can be CentOS PC with two network interfaces.

Comment: exactly this was come in my mind in this case do i have to start dhcp in centos machine ? and make bridge to pass the data or let them work as it is  and NAT between LAN And WAN on centos ?
what you think it works ?

Comment: With a « bridge », I am not sure IP packet comes to the `iptable` handling functions. A bridge is typically at a lower level but I may be wrong. A NAT between the internal LAN and your ISP LAN could makes you use two different IP range without causing issues (your internal addresses aren’t known and routed adequately by your ISP). But if you want anything from the internal LAN pass through squid, NAT is not needed. A dhcp server should be set to make it easier for internal PC to get new addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a proxy, but you need a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy).

Which means you need an extra machine (CentOS, if you prefer) where you run the transparent proxy, you need to change your networking setup (e.g. on your internal DHCP server) to make this machine the default gateway for all your Windows boxes where you need proxying, and you need to set up iptable rules on the extra machine to transparently pick out HTTP connections and proxy them, and forward the rest of the traffic.

Google e.g. "set up transparent squid proxy", there are plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice 
Yes it make sense. and it worked fine